# What is the input data structure for HERMES toolbox for EEG connectivity analysis?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I wanted to use HERMES for connectivity analysis of my EEG dataset which includes 32 subjects and 40 trials for each subject. There are two conditions/classes. I do not know how my data should be defined to be known by HERMES!
Could you please kindly tell me what should the structure of input to HERMES be?
Or is there a better alternative like Brainstorm to use in my MATLAB scripts (I mean without using its GUI manually and do my connectivity analysis automatically by using loops instead)?

Any help in this regards is greatly appreciated.

[HERMES toolbox](http://hermes.ctb.upm.es/)

[Brainstorm toolbox](http://neuroimage.usc.edu/brainstorm/)

Comment: As HERMES is a third-party toolbox developed by the Universidad Politécnica de Madrid, I think you're best off emailing them, as I doubt there's many people here that have worked with their toolbox before.

Comment: @Adriaan  I emailed them but they have not responded yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERMES accepts MAT files (*.mat) and Fieldtrip structures.

MAT files should consist on one single matrix with as many columns as channels and as many rows as temporal points (and, in the case of event-related data, the third dimension will be for the different trials).
For example, for one subject and condition: a matrix of (30 channels x 1000 samples (x 50 trials)).
Therefore, to be able to load your data easily, you'll need to obtain your MAT files as described above.

Thanks to Guiomar Niso for providing this answer.